# Can I parse app.config custom sections to List data structure?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, app-config

I have  the following app.config custom section:

```
<myCustomSection>
    <person1 name = "John" age = "30">
    <person2 name = "Mike" age = "46">
</muCustomSection>
```

And the following code to parse it with help of  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager:

```
public class MyCustomCongifuration : ConfigurationSection {
     [ConfigurationProperty("person1", IsRequired = true)]
     public PersonConfiguration Person1
     {
         get => (PersonConfiguration)this["person1"];
         set => this["person1"] = value;
     }

     [ConfigurationProperty("person2", IsRequired = true)]
     public PersonConfiguration Person2
     {
         get => (PersonConfiguration)this["person2"];
         set => this["person2"] = value;
     }
}
```

I want to refactor the code to use the following app.config:

```
<myCustomSection>
    <person name = "John" age = "30">
    <person name = "Mike" age = "46">
</muCustomSection>
```

And I expect to get a List of PersonConfiguration in MyCustomConfiguration object:

```
var configuration = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("myCustomSection") as MyCustomConfiguration;
var persons = configuration.Persons; // returns List<PersonConfiguration>
```

Is it possible and how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET Framework does support having lists of items in its configuration, but not quite as you have listed. If you look at the `appSettings` section of your file, you can see an example of a collection:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="foo" value="Fizz" />
  <add key="bar" value="Buzz" />
</appSettings>
```

This is built on the specialised collection `ConfigurationElementCollection` which allows you to model `add` `remove` and `clear` functions as XML in order to build up your list of items.

First, mark the `name` property of the `PersonConfiguration` as the key. I'm assuming the name of the person is suitable as the key identifier; if you come up with a different identifier, use that.

```
[ConfigurationProperty("name", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
public string Name
{
    get { return (string)this["name"]; }
    set { this["name"] = value; }
}
```

Create your custom collection deriving from `ConfigurationElementCollection` so you return the key value for a person.

```
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(PersonConfiguration))]
public class PersonConfigurationElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    protected override PersonConfiguration CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new PersonConfiguration();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((PersonConfiguration)element).Name;
    }
}
```

Then add this collection to your custom configuration section's class:

```
public class MyCustomCongifuration : ConfigurationSection
{
     [ConfigurationProperty("people", IsDefaultCollection = true)]
     public PersonConfigurationElementCollection People
     {
         get { return (PersonConfigurationElementCollection)this["people"]; }
         set { this["people"] = value; }
     }
}
```

You can now create a collection of people as such:

```
<myCustomSection>
  <people>
    <add name="John" age="30" />
    <add name="Mike" age="46" />
  </people>
</muCustomSection>
```

If you want to turn that configuration collection to a list, you can use a little bit of Linq:

```
var configuration = (MyCustomConfiguration)ConfigurationManager
    .GetSection("myCustomSection");
var people = configuration.People.Cast<PersonConfiguration>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how can you do that with ConfigurationManager, but a different approach could be using the XML Linq:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("C:\path\to\file.config");
var persons = doc.Element("configuration").Element("myCustomSection").Descendants("person");

foreach (var person in persons)
{
    var Name = Attribute("name").Value;
    var Age = Attribute("age").Value;
}
```

You could remove a item using:

```
doc.Element("configuration").Elements("myCustomSection").First(s =>(string)s.Attribute("name") == "Name you want to find").Remove();
```

Comment: What's type of person?

Comment: persons assumes type of IEnumerable<XElement>, with each person being a XElement type.